# Three JS raycaster, find intersections as mouse moves

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I have a feeling that this approach is entirely wrong as I can't manage to get a proper performance for my website.

Here is the main code that I would like you to see:

```
onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    if ( this.isUserInteracting === true ) {
      this.lon = ( this.onMouseDownMouseX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + this.onMouseDownLon;
      this.lat = ( event.clientY - this.onMouseDownMouseY ) * 0.1 + this.onMouseDownLat;
    }
    this.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    this.mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    if( !this.state.VR ){
      this.raycaster.setFromCamera( this.mouse, this.camera );
      var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects( this.indicatorHotspotPlane );

      if( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        this.actualIntersect = intersects[0];

        $('html,body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        if(!intersects[ 0 ].object.isAction){
          this.marker.material.opacity = 1;
          this.marker.lookAt( intersects[ 0 ].face.normal );
          this.marker.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );
          this.marker.position.y = this.marker.position.y + 30;
          if( intersects[ 0 ].point.x >= 0 ){
            this.marker.position.x = this.marker.position.x - 30;
          }else{
            this.marker.position.x = this.marker.position.x + 30;
          } 
        }
      } else {
        this.actualIntersect = null;
        $('html,body').css('cursor', 'move');
        this.marker.material.opacity = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

I believe that raycaster.intersectObjects is a very expensive operation to run inside this kind of event handler.

If I comment this piece of code, everything runs nicely.

Is there any other way of finding intersections when mouse is moving without having performance problems?

this.indicatorHotspotPlane is an array with maybe 5 objects like this one:

```
var hotspotPlane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( hotpot.width , hotpot.height ) );
```

And my scene contains these objects and a sphere geometry with a texture on it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html).

Whats' happening here:

1. The scene is rendered to an off-screen render target using a unique solid color per shape.
2. The mouse coordinates are checked against the render target X,Y coordinates, and gets the color (if any) under the mouse.
3. The color is checked against a map of color->mesh
4. The associate mesh is updated to reflect its "highlighted" state.
5. The main scene is re-rendered, with the part now highlighted.

There is still a cost of doing this: You will incur an extra render every time you need to refresh your render target. Also, if your scene is REALLY BIG (taking a long time to render), it may perform just as poorly as raycasting. Still, the moral of the story is that it is *much* easier to read a color value from a buffer than it is to perform a raycast.

Another caveat is that this will only work for the nearest shape (the equivalent of `intersects[0]`). This is because occluded shapes won't have their colors exposed (their colors are completely covered by other shapes). So if you need to get ALL of the shapes under your mouse, then raycasting is still the best option.

**Additional Info:**

I overlooked part of your code and jumped straight into solving the raytracing problem. After a deeper review, here is some extra info:

It looks like you're taking whatever object you intersect, and are checking a specific property:

```
if(!intersects[ 0 ].object.isAction){
```

Using the method described above, you would check for that property on whatever object you get out of your color map.

To get the intersection point, you WILL need to perform a raycast, but now it will only happen if the object under your mouse passes your test first, rather than every time your mouse moves.

The raycast *will* occur for every mouse move event while the cursor is over an appropriate object, so you may want to reconsider how often you need to update your marker (maybe every N frames), or perhaps set the marker only the first time you encounter a particular shape. I don't know your use-case, so perhaps this isn't viable.

Comment: Hello again TheJim. Thanks for your answer. I developed the new solution. however my meshes are using image maps (png) and so the color is not uniform and/or unique for each one of them.

Comment: It is working, but now I have problems trying to identify the object that my GPUpicker found. My solution is based on this:https://github.com/brianxu/GPUPicker

Comment: @rmartrenado I'm not familiar with that library. From a quick look it will return an `intersects` object much like `raycaster.intersectObject` (note: singular). It will be a single intersection result object, not an array of intersection result objects.

Comment: And what about the Octrees? https://codepen.io/Ryan-James/pen/mJMBwP?editors=1000 Perhaps we could benefit a lot from it. I will try tomorrow... do you know anything about this approach?

Comment: Octrees provide faster queries because they reduce your query population, and the calculation for an intersection with a branch (just a world-space bounding box) is faster than an intersection with a mesh. The benefit will depend on the depth of your octree. Too shallow, and you'll test more objects than you need to. Too refined, and you may waste an entire sub-branch on a single mesh. You'll also need to refresh your octree if you add new items to your scene. It's also worth noting they're super-fast when intersecting nothing. TL;DR: It's definitely worth a shot.

Comment: All my mesh are a planebuffergeometry. So they are 2d so to say. I'll try in a minute and let you know, thanks!